# Fail Test Case if Exception is Raised and Handled in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, automated-tests, python-unittest

Take a look at the following test case:

```
def test_1_check_version(self):
    try:
        self.version()
        print('\n')
    except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as error_message:
        print("Sorry Connection could not be established because "+str(error_message))
```

Above is the test case of many test cases I am writing in Unittest of Python, and now I am running it to check that connection of the database is connected or not.

If yes, then it will pass 'Version number of Database'.

If not, then it will throw an exception, which I have handled.

After running this rest case, the test case is showing pass in any testing framework (Robot, unittest, pytest) that I have used.

But, I want this test case to fail because it is not the result I am looking for.

Handling exceptions because I want to see the only error message rather than all those red lines of exception.

I am open for any kind of suggestion, whether it involves removing exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior of passing the test is the expected.. tests only fail if you receive a result which was not expected in some assertion.

In your case, if you want the exception to be thrown, you should use:

```
self.assertRaises(cx_Oracle.DatabaseError, self.version())
```

If you want to check if the version is correct, then use:

```
self.assertEqual(XXX, self.version())
```

where *XXX* is the value of *self.version()* you're expecting

Comment: I am getting a value via method, can it be handled within assertEqual.

Comment: sure! Imagine that you have a foo() method which returns 1. By doing self.assertEqual(1, foo()) you'll pass the test. If you're expecting to get "2",  self.assertEqual(2, foo()) will fail

Answer (score 0):

> since version 2.7: Added the ability to use assertRaises() as a context manager

So the recommended usage would be

```
with self.assertRaises(SomeException) as cm:
    self.version()

the_exception = cm.exception
self.assertEqual(the_exception.error_code, 3)
```

[see document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html)